# Apache Beam + SparkRunner: how to pass 'spark.yarn.queue' param

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-beam

I have a Spark cluster and I want to run Apache Beam pipeline written in Python there.

In order to get Spark job executed, I need to submit it to specific queue, that's how I do it in Spark job code:

```
sparkConf = SparkConf()    
  .set("spark.yarn.queue", "my.specific-queue-name")
```

For Apache Beam, I use default options provided in docs and receive 'FutureTimeoutError':

```
pipelineOptions = PipelineOptions([
    "--runner=PortableRunner",
    "--job_endpoint=localhost:8099",
    "--environment_type=LOOPBACK"
])
```

I assume it happens because yarn.queue is not specified, but I can't find how to set in Python.

Comment: I'm guessing the FutureTimeoutError is happening because there is no Beam job service running at `--job_endpoint=localhost:8099`. Instructions for setting up a job service are available on the [Beam Spark webpage](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark).

Comment: You also should check out the unresolved issue [BEAM-8970](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-8970) - setting up Beam on Yarn will require some special setup, and as far as I know no one's documented how to do it yet.